# Access title inside application in ionic push notification

Tags: php, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app using ionic framework.I have successfully implement push notification.Notifications are successfully coming on my device.Everything works perfectly. Now i want to access title inside my application.
Here is my code:

```
 $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function(){
     //$scope.identified = true;
     //alert('User ID ' + user.user_id);
     //alert("here");
     $ionicPush.register({
      canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
      canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
      canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
      canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
      onNotification: function(notification) {
      alert(notification.title);//here I want to get title
        // Handle new push notifications here
        // console.log(notification);
        return true;
```

I am using php for send notification:
here is code:

```
$msg = array
(
    'notId' => time(),
    'message'       => 'Technovault is awesome!!!',
    'title'         => 'Title',//get this title inside my app
    'smallIcon'     =>'icon',
    //'path'          =>'www.google.com'    
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'              => $msg
);

$headers = array 
(
    'Authorization: key=' . 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
}


 Please help
```

Comment: can you paste here what is result of `console.log(notification);` line and in what way you want to use this title ?

Comment: I get only message which I send with my php script

Comment: try console.log(notification.payload.title) and see what it shows.

Comment: Now I want when i click on notification it will go in particular state.

Comment: thanks.....problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access title from payload object which have strucuture like `notification.payload.title` , and every notification has parameter `foreground` having value `false` or `true`. When you come to application by clicking on notification then it will have `false` value, so you use this like:

```
onNotification: function(notification) {
  if(notification.foreground === false){
    //put here your logic to go in any state
  }
}
```